# No GPU rendering on Mac?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, osx

Is it really true that it's not possible to render on the GPU with Cycles on a newer Mac with an AMD GPU...?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, in favor of Apple's new Metal API. ProRender or AppleSeed might work...